# I am having trouble with programming a death counter without messing up other scripts I already have done on Roblox Studio

Tags: roblox

I want the leaderstats to display wins and deaths at the same time. I have the leaderboard showing both except when I try to add a death counter. The problem is that it only shows the deaths on the board then. I also want the deaths and wins to save, and I can't figure that out either.

I tried putting the counter on the same script as the leaderstats, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

here use this script and put it in serverscriptservice

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(Player)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder", Player)
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"

    local Deaths = Instance.new("NumberValue", leaderstats)
    Deaths.Name = "Deths"
    Deaths.Value = 0
    
    local Wins = Instance.new("NumberValue", leaderstats)
    Wins.Name = "Wins"
    Wins.Value = 0
end)
```

and for the counter you should add a gui and make a local script in side it and write this script

```
while true do
    --the location of your gui and texlabel = your deths in leaderstas
end
```

for the data you need to watch some videos and tutriols for sync and async
for exmaple i rather you wathcing ThevOftheKing videos